# Get image from csi camera on google dev board

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I am trying to get an image with coral camera on dev board mini, but have a problem to construct right gstreamer pipeline. I am trying this one

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device='/dev/video1' num_buffers=1 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! jpegenc ! filesink location=image.jpg
```

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device='/dev/video1' num_buffers=1 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert !jpegenc ! filesink location=image.jpg
```

but I am getting only green image. How to construct the proper pipeline?